# An identity involving summation (Proving associativity)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(a_t), (b_t), (c_t) \in R^{\mathbb{N}^n}$, where $R$ is a ring. Then I want to show that
$$\sum_{\substack{u,\ v \ \in \ \mathbb{N}^n \\ u+v = t}}\sum_{\substack{p,\ q \ \in \ \mathbb{N}^n \\ p+q=v}}a_ub_pc_q = \sum_{\substack{u,\ v \ \in \ \mathbb{N}^n \\ u+v = t}}\sum_{\substack{p,\ q \ \in \ \mathbb{N}^n \\ p+q=u}}a_pb_qc_v$$
where $t = (t_1, \dots , t_n)$ and $u + v = (u_1, \dots , u_n) + (v_1, \dots , v_n) = (u_1+v_1, \dots , u_n + v_n)$.

Actually what I want to prove is that the product defined on the set $R^{\mathbb{N}^n}$ is associative. The product of two elements $(a_t),(b_t) \in R^{\mathbb{N}^n}$ is defined as
$$(a_t)\cdot(b_t) = (c_t), \quad \text{where } \quad c_t = \sum_{\substack{u,\ v \ \in \ \mathbb{N}^n \\ u+v = t}}a_ub_v$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a simple substitution both sides are equal to
$$\sum_{\large u,v,w \in \mathbb{N}^n,\, u+v+w=t} a_u b_v c_w.$$

Comment: Can you please write down the substitution because I couldn't see it.

Comment: There is only *one* substitution which you can make. Out of $(u,v),(p,q)$ with $u+v=t$ and $p+q=v$ you have to find a triple whose sum is $t$ ...